# Fields resetting after selecting in select2 during inline edit

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have issue regarding the livewire inline edit. I have a table records with edit button, upon clicking edit the data of the clicked row, will populate to edit form, my edit form has a few select2, my problem is If I select a value from select2 all the other edit fields will reset.

This is my record table.
[image: record table]

This is the edit form after clicking the edit button
[image: edit form]

After selecting a value from the product dropdown, all the other fields will reset and lose all their value
[image: fields loses its values]

Can anyone please tell me the problem and a way to fix this?

Here is my code

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Inventory\Shipment;

use App\Models\Admin\ProductType;
use App\Models\Admin\Brand;
use App\Models\Admin\UnitOfMeasureItems;
use App\Models\Inventory\Product;
use App\Models\Inventory\Shipment\IncomingStockProduct;
use Livewire\Component;

class IncomingStockProducts extends Component
{
    public $editedProductIndex = null;
    public $incoming_stock;
    public $products = [];
    public $uoms;
    public $product_list = [];
    public $product_types;
    public $brands;

    public $selectedProduct = null, $selectedProductType = null, $unit_of_measure_item_id, $quantity, $unit_cost, $total_cost, $brand_id, $model, $serial_number;
    public $editSelectedProductType = null;
    public $showAddForm = false;

    protected $listeners = [
        'selectedProduct',
        'selectedProductType',
        'editSelectedProductType',
        "products.*.product_id" => 'updatedEditSelectedProduct',
        'refreshProductList' => 'refresh'
    ];

    public function mount($incoming_stock)
    {
        $this->incoming_stock = $incoming_stock;
        $this->products = $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts->load(['product.productType', 'brand'])->toArray();
        $this->product_types = ProductType::all();
        $this->brands = Brand::all();
        $this->uoms = collect();
        $this->product_list = collect();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.inventory.shipment.incoming-stock-products');
    }

    public function updatedSelectedProductType($product_type_id)
    {
        if (!is_null($product_type_id)) {
            $this->product_list = Product::where('product_type_id', $product_type_id)->get();
        }
    }

    public function updatedEditSelectedProductType($product_type_id)
    {
        if (!is_null($product_type_id)) {
            $this->product_list = Product::where('product_type_id', $product_type_id)->get();
        }
    }

    public function updatedSelectedProduct($product_id)
    {
        if (!is_null($product_id)) {
            $uom = Product::where('id', $product_id)->first();
            $this->uoms = UnitOfMeasureItems::where('unit_of_measure_id', $uom->unit_of_measure_id)->get();
        }
    }

    public function updatedEditSelectedProduct($product_id)
    {
        if (!is_null($product_id)) {
            $uom = Product::where('id', $product_id)->first();
            $this->uoms = UnitOfMeasureItems::where('unit_of_measure_id', $uom->unit_of_measure_id)->get();
        }
    }

    public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('select2');
    }



    public function editProduct($productIndex)
    {
        $this->editSelectedProductType = $this->products[$productIndex]['product']['product_type_id'];
        $this->product_list = Product::where('product_type_id', $this->editSelectedProductType)->get();
        $this->uoms = UnitOfMeasureItems::where('unit_of_measure_id', $this->products[$productIndex]['product']['unit_of_measure_id'])->get();
        $this->showAddForm = false;
        $this->editedProductIndex = $productIndex;
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('edit-product');
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $this->products = $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts->load(['product.productType', 'brand'])->toArray();
        $this->editedProductIndex = null;
        $this->showAddForm = true;
    }

    public function cancelAddProduct()
    {
        $this->showAddForm = false;
    }

    public function cancelEditProduct()
    {
        $this->editedProductIndex = null;
    }

    public function refresh()
    {
        $this->products = $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts->load(['product.productType', 'brand'])->toArray();
    }

    public function clearInputs()
    {
        $this->selectedProduct = '';
        $this->selectedProductType = '';
        $this->unit_of_measure_item_id = '';
        $this->quantity = '';
        $this->unit_cost = '';
        $this->total_cost = '';
        $this->brand_id = '';
        $this->model = '';
        $this->serial_number = '';
    }

    public function storeProductItems()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'selectedProduct' => 'required|numeric|exists:products,id',
            'serial_number' => 'required_if:product_type_id,1|nullable|string|unique:incoming_stock_products,serial_number',
            'model' => 'required_if:product_type_id,1|nullable',
            'brand_id' => 'required|numeric|exists:brands,id',
            'unit_of_measure_item_id' => 'required|numeric|exists:unit_of_measure_items,id',
            'quantity' => 'required',
            'unit_cost' => 'required',
            'total_cost' => 'required',

        ]);

        $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts()->create([
            'product_id' => $this->selectedProduct,
            'serial_number' => $this->serial_number,
            'model' => $this->model,
            'brand_id' => $this->brand_id,
            'unit_of_measure_item_id' => $this->unit_of_measure_item_id,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'unit_cost' => $this->unit_cost,
            'total_cost' => $this->total_cost,
        ]);

        $this->showAddForm = false;
        $this->clearInputs();
        $this->emit('refreshProductList');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('flash-message', ['message' => 'Product Added Successfully!', 'type' => 'success']);
    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #24d5b8" colspan="10">LIST OF INCOMING PRODUCTS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="wd-10p">TYPE</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">PRODUCT</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">SERIAL NO</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">BRAND</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">MODEL</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">UOM</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">QUANTITY</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">UNIT COST</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">TOTAL</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {{-- {{ dd($products) }} --}}
        <tbody>
            @forelse($products as $index => $product)
                <tr wire:key="product-list-{{ $index }}">
                    <form>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['product']['product_type']['title'] }}
                            @else
                                <select wire:model="editSelectedProductType" id="editSelectedProductType"
                                    class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Product Type</option>
                                    @foreach ($product_types as $product_type)
                                        <option value="{{ $product_type->id }}">{{ $product_type->title }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('editSelectedProductType')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['product']['product_name'] }}
                            @else
                                <select wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.product_id" id="edit_product_id"
                                    class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                    @foreach ($product_list as $product)
                                        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->product_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('products.{{ $index }}.product_id')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['serial_number'] ?? '' }}
                            @else
                                <input type="text" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.serial_number"
                                    class="form-control">
                                @error('editedProduct.serial_number')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['brand']['name'] ?? '' }}
                            @else
                                <select wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.brand_id" id="edit_brand_id"
                                    class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                                    @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                                        <option value="{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('editedProduct.serial_number')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['model'] ?? '' }}
                            @else
                                <input type="text" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.model"
                                    class="form-control">
                                @error('editedProduct.uom')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['uom'] ?? 'UNIT' }}
                            @else
                                <select wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.unit_of_measure_item_id"
                                    id="edit_uom" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select UOM</option>
                                    @foreach ($uoms as $uom)
                                        <option value="{{ $uom->id }}">{{ $uom->uom_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('products.{{ $index }}.unit_of_measure_item_id')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['quantity'] }}
                            @else
                                <input type="text" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.quantity"
                                    class="form-control">
                                @error('products.{{ $index }}.quantity')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['unit_cost'] }}
                            @else
                                <input type="text" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.unit_cost"
                                    class="form-control">
                                @error('products.{{ $index }}.unit_cost')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                {{ $product['total_cost'] }}
                            @else
                                <input type="text" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.total_cost"
                                    class="form-control" wire:ignore>
                                @error('products.{{ $index }}.total_cost')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon btn-md"
                                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="EDIT"
                                    wire:click.prevent="editProduct({{ $index }})"><i
                                        class="fe fe-edit"></i></button>
                            @else
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon btn-md"
                                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="SAVE"
                                    wire:click.prevent="updateProduct({{ $index }})"><i
                                        class="fe fe-save"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                    title="" data-bs-original-title="CANCEL"
                                    wire:click.prevent="cancelProductEdit({{ $index }})">
                                    <i class="fe fe-x"></i>
                                </button>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="text-center">No products found.</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse

            @if ($showAddForm)
                <tr>
                    <form action="">
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <select wire:model="selectedProductType" id="selectedProductType" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Product Type</option>
                                    @foreach ($product_types as $product_type)
                                        <option value="{{ $product_type->id }}">{{ $product_type->title }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @error('selectedProduct')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <select wire:model="selectedProduct" id="selectedProduct" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                    @foreach ($product_list as $product)
                                        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->product_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @error('selectedProduct')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </td>
                        <td><input wire:model="serial_number" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <select wire:model="brand_id" id="brand_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                                    @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                                        <option value="{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @error('brand_id')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </td>
                        <td><input wire:model="model" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <select wire:model.defer="unit_of_measure_item_id" id="unit_of_measure_item_id"
                                    class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select UOM</option>
                                    @foreach ($uoms as $uom)
                                        <option value="{{ $uom->id }}">{{ $uom->uom_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @error('unit_of_measure_item_id')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </td>
                        <td><input wire:model="quantity" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input wire:model="unit_cost" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input wire:model="total_cost" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <button wire:click.prevent="storeProductItems" type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-info-light button-icon btn-md" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                    title="" data-bs-original-title="SAVE"><i class="fe fe-save"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon"
                                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="DELETE"
                                    wire:click="cancelAddProduct">
                                    <i class="fe fe-x"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="align-item-left">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="addProduct">Add Product</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@push('jsplugins')
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('select2', event => {
            $('#selectedProductType').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#selectedProductType').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('selectedProductType', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#selectedProduct').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#selectedProduct').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('selectedProduct', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#unit_of_measure_item_id').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#unit_of_measure_item_id').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('unit_of_measure_item_id', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#brand_id').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#brand_id').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('brand_id', e.target.value);
            });

            // edit

            $('#edit_uom').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#edit_uom').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('products.*.unit_of_measure_item_id', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#edit_brand_id').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#edit_brand_id').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('products.*.brand_id', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#edit_product_id').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#edit_product_id').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('products.*.product_id', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#editSelectedProductType').select2({
                width: '100%'
            });

            $('#editSelectedProductType').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('editSelectedProductType', e.target.value);
            });

        });

        window.addEventListener('flash-message', event => {
            toastr[event.detail.type](event.detail.message);
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!Managed to fix this and got it working. just added wire:ignore and used ajax/jquery to manage dependent dropdown, so that it does not always re-render whenever I got a new action on the frontend.